# How to implement a Sitecore Commerce Minion

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am new to Sitecore commerce Minions.

I wanted to create a Minion which runs for every 30 minutes to update the Product values.

I am getting the Products properties from external source.

What changes do I need to make ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to declare your minion on the environment definition for your minions environment.

In the Sitecore.Commerce.Engine project is the JSON file PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceMinions-1.0.0.json which is the definition for the habitat minions environment. This is the active environment on the commerce minions web site (one of 4 in IIS installed as part of commerce).

First of all you need to declare your minion in a json :

```
{
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.MinionPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
    "WakeupInterval": "00:05:00",
    "ListToWatch": "",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Plugin.MyProject.Import.ImportMinion, Plugin.MyProject.Import",
    "ItemsPerBatch": 10,
    "SleepBetweenBatches": 500
}
```

You need to declare your class which inherits from **Minion** class

```
 namespace Plugin.MyProject.Import
{
    public class ImportMinion : Minion
    {
        protected IImportMinionMinionPipeline MinionPipeline { get; set; }

        public override void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger logger, MinionPolicy policy, CommerceEnvironment environment, CommerceContext globalContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(serviceProvider, logger, policy, environment, globalContext);
            MinionPipeline = serviceProvider.GetService<IImportMinionMinionPipeline>();
        }

        public override async Task<MinionRunResultsModel> Run()
        {
            this.Logger.LogInformation("ImportMinion running");

            var commerceContext = new CommerceContext(this.Logger, this.MinionContext.TelemetryClient, null);
            commerceContext.Environment = this.Environment;

            CommercePipelineExecutionContextOptions executionContextOptions = new CommercePipelineExecutionContextOptions(commerceContext, null, null, null, null, null);

            MinionRunResultsModel res = await this.MinionPipeline.Run(new MinionRunResultsModel(), executionContextOptions);

            return new MinionRunResultsModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the changes in the json files you need to bootrastrap your commerce engine.

Please have  a look for more informations on next links :

https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/03/sitecore-experience-commerce-creating.html 
https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/05/sitecore-experience-commerce-minion-to.html
https://github.com/commerceengineplugins/sampleminion

Comment: I tried to hit the Minion from Postman and i got the below error.{
      "MessageDate":"2018-08-08T08:32:41.4097457Z","Code":"Error","Text":"Minion Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SAP.Minion.SAPProductSyncMinion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SAP was not found.","CommerceTermKey":"MinionNotFound"
    }

Comment: did you bootstrap  your commerce engine?

Comment: HI Vlad, Yes I did. I am getting the below error in "CommerceMinions" IIS website log file.[MinionStartup] Environment='HabitatMinions', 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SAP.Minion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SAP'
11 05:17:38 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Core.block.StartEnvironmentMinions ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Comment: The problem with wrong assembly name added in Minion config file. Now this is working as expected.

Comment: Great, glad I could help you